# How to add SSN mask to a kendo grid filter?

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that displays many columns. I have a column for SSN. When user clicks on the filter and types in 123-45-6789 it filters the correct SSN, however, when user types in 123456789 nothing is filtered. Is there any way that it can filter only 9 numbers with or without dashes.

```
      columns.Bound(p => p.SSN)
        .Title("SSN")
        .Width(100);

    .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "height: 579px; width: 110%"})
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
    .Extra(false)
    .Operators(operators => operators
          .ForString(str => str.Clear()
              .Contains("Contains")
              .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
              .StartsWith("Starts with")
              .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to")
          )
      )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the filter to use a `kendoMaskedTextBox` like this:

```
<script>
    function ssnFilter(element) {
        element.kendoMaskedTextBox({
            mask: "000-00-0000"
        });
    };
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<YourModel>()
    .Name("YourGridName")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.SSN).Filterable(f => f.UI("ssnFilter"));
    }
)
```

[Kendo MaskedTextBox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index) documentation

[Kendo Grid Filter Customization](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization) documentation